# How to acces JournalArticlePermission from custom portlet

Tags: permissions, liferay

I would like to check if the current user has the permissions to update a journal article. To do so, I would like to call JournalArticlePermission.check() from a custom portlet, but the class JournalArticlePermission is not reachable from my portlet's class loader.

Calling

```
return permissionChecker.hasPermission(groupId, jaClassName, resourcePrimKey, ActionKeys.UPDATE);
```

works but it bypasses all the staging logic implemented in the helper class.

What's the clean way to check the permissions on a journal article ?

The same question as posted [here on liferay forums](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/23525620), but am not fully convinced by the answers proposed, i.e. using `PortalClassInvoker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no real "clean" way to do that.

The permission helper classes are part of portal-impl package, so can't be used in a custom portlet directly, as discussed in [this thread on liferay forums](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/28893856), with valuable input from Harish Kumar and David H Nebinger.

The options are:

- copy-paste the logic from the core helper classes, with obvious consequences on maintenance
- bypass the helper code and go directly to the lower level checks, leaving aside potentially valuable checks (such as staging permissions).